# How to use Notion API to create a database item with a particular select tag as a property?

Tags: notion-api

I have an API POST request that creates an item within my Notion database. But I want to add it with a particular Select tag as a property. This is the JSON I'm sending:

```
{
"parent":{
    "database_id":"ce0efca3907b4e1baace71b03a6c1881"
}
,
"properties":{
        "title":[
            {
                "text":{
                    "content": "Provided Input"
                }
            }
        ]
}
,
"properties_value":
  {
        "Kanban Status":{
               "select": {
                "name": "To Do",
                "id":"ce0efca3907b4e1baace71b03a6c1881"
        }
        }
  }
}
```

It successfully adds the item to the database, but the select property (Kanban Status) is unchanged. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear why you have Kanban Status in a separate "properties_value" object. It should look something like:

```
"parent":{
    "database_id":"ce0efca3907b4e1baace71b03a6c1881"
    },
    "properties": {
        "Name": {
            "title": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "content": "Provided Input"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "Kanban Status": {
            "select": {
                "name": "To Do"
            }
        }
    }
}
```